# How to generate Trial Balance report by combining Profit & Loss and Balance Sheet reports using Xero API

Tags: xero-api

We want to generate a Trial Balance report by combining Profit & Loss and Balance Sheet reports from Xero API. This is so that we can include tracking category as a dimension to the trial balance report. However, we noticed that there is no credit and debit classification on P&L and Balance Sheet reports: we only have positive/negative numbers and account ID for each entry. In this case, how can we know if an entry in these two reports is credit or debit?

We have reviewed reports in our account and we think it might be possible to do it by using account IDs. Using account ID, we can retrieve [account class](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/accounting/types#accounts) and then as far as I can see:

- negative values are considered debit, positive values are considered
  credit for: REVENUE, LIABILITY, EQUITY
- negative values are considered credit, positive values are considered debit for: EXPENSE, ASSET

However, I do not know if this a fact or just the reports I checked happened to be in this way and that there might be certain cases this logic will not handle.